# Generating random number in a non-power-of-2 range from random bits

Tags: algorithm, random

I have an infinite stream of random bits.

I want to generate a random number between 0 and 999 (inclusive).

Is the best algorithm:

- pull 10 bits
- if their value is less than 1,000, use that,
- else pull another 10 bits.

Or is there a better way?  Perhaps an algorithm which is guaranteed to consume only a finite number of bits?

Comment: Why not just modulo 1000? Do you want the number to be identically distributed?

Comment: Yes, I want a uniform distribution of random numbers.

Comment: I *think* that there is not better way, as 1/10th cannot be exactly represented in base 2, due to the factor of five.

Comment: Feed the random stream to arithmetic decoder / range arithmetic decoder. I dont have a proof though, but it might be possible that the non-determinism in the traditional rejection algorithm has its parallel in the arithmetic algorithm in a form of infinitely long stream of decimals required for a decision.

Comment: The algorithm will consume a finite number of bits with probability 1. You can't put an upper-bound on the number of bits consumed. But you can put a "high-probability upper-bound" on the number of bits. 1000 is not a power of 2, but it is pretty close to 1024 which is a power of 2; the probability to consume more than 30 bits is (24/1000)^3 = 0.0014%

Comment: You can also save a few bits by remembering by how much you've exceeded 999. If you exceed 999 that means the number is somewhere between [1000, 1023]. Subtract 1000 and you get a uniform random number in [0, 23], which is worth approximately 5 bits.

Comment: I'm sure in the past I read the general question "Simulate a n-sided dice with an k-sided dice?" on https://math.stackexchange.com , with a great answer that explained: (1) you can guarantee a bounded number of rolls iff every prime divisor of n is also a divisor of k; (2) how to use the k-die as efficiently as possible if you're not in case 1. But I can't find this question and answer again.

Comment: Please define what you mean by “better”. Fewer bits required? Computationally faster? Also, are you assuming that the sampled bits are independent and that zeros and ones are equiprobable? If, say, ones occur with probability 0.6 you’d need to use more bits and clever tricks to get the outcome uniform over [0,999].

Comment: @rajashekar Using modulo 1000 would yield [modulo bias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/2166798).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random integer in the range \[0,n\] from a stream of random bits without wasting bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations like this it is important to make a distinction between "infinite" and "unbounded".

In your case, you'll be able to generate a random number with a finite number of bits with probability 1, but you cannot guarantee an upper-bound on the needed number of bits with probability 1.

We summarise this by saying "The number of bits required is finite but unbounded."

However, you can guarantee relatively-high probability upper-bounds.

Even with the naive strategy of pulling 10 bits, discarding the generated number if it's higher than 1000, and starting over, you have only probability 24/1024 = 0.2% of needing more than 10 bits, probability (24/1024)^2 = 0.05% of needing more than 20 bits, probability (24/1024)^3 = 0.001% of needing more than 30 bits, probability (24/1024)^4 = 0.00003% of needing more than 40 bits, etc.

You can be slightly more efficient by not discarding the extra bits of information when you reject a number, ie by remembering by how much you've exceeded 999. If you exceed 999 that means the number is somewhere between [1000, 1023]. There are 24 different ways to exceed 999, and they are uniformly distributed. Subtract 1000 and you get a uniform random number in [0, 23], which is worth approximately 4.5 bits of randomness, which you can use for your next generated random number.

Here is an implementation of this method in python:

```py
def gen_random(bitstream, n):
    x = 0  # random number generated so far
    m = 1  # x is always uniform in range [0, m-1]
    for bit in bitstream:
        x = x * 2 + bit
        m *= 2
        if m >= n:
            if x < n:
                return x
            else:
                x = x - n
                m = m - n

from itertools import repeat
from random import getrandbits

bitstream = map(getrandbits, repeat(1))
print('Uniform random number between 0 and 999: ', gen_random(bitstream, 1000))
```

Note: it terms of practical speed of execution, the above code is inefficient because it calls `getrandbits(1)` ten times instead of calling `getrandbits(10)` one time - but in terms of number of bits pulled from the stream, it is optimal.

Comment: How is this better than just tossing the high bit, shifting left, and getting one more random bit for the low bit?  That's the way to optimize the number of random bits needed.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have trouble parsing the algorithm that you summarised in one sentence, but I suspect you're describing exactly the same algorithm as I am, so I guess you're asking "How is this better than itself?"

Comment: You're talking about using the remainder which you call 4.5 bits of randomness.  I'm talking about using the lower 9 bits.  Seems totally different to me.

Comment: @MarkRansom Seems totally different to you because you know what algorithm you're talking about. I do not know what algorithm you're talking about. How can I answer your question about whether it is better or different or what.

Comment: @MarkRansom Apology. My previous comment sounds a lot more aggressive that I meant it to.

Comment: Mark's algorithm can be explained by assuming an infinite stream on random bits b0, b1, ...b9, b10, b11, ... If the 10-bit number b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 (b0 is the high-order bit) is >= 1000 then try b1 b2 ... b10 and so on until success.

Comment: No apology necessary, I forgot some people don't think in terms of bit manipulation.  It's easy to see you using `* 2` instead of `<< 1`.  To put it in terms you'd understand, on overflow I'd use `x -= m//2` and `m = m//2` and `m` would overflow again on the next pass of the loop.

Comment: @MarkRansom I wrote `<<` at first but `<<` and `+` have counterintuitive priorities when used together, so I figured I should either stick to bit-manipulation operators entirely, or use `*` and `+`, but not use `<<` and `+` together.

Comment: @Stef The comment in your code says `x` is always uniform, but that wouldn’t be true if zeroes and ones occur with unequal probabilities. That’s something von Neumann worried about for Monte Carlo simulations in the 1940’s. He proposed taking independent bits in pairs, rejecting and resampling if the bit pair was a decimal 0 or 3 (i.e., identical bits), or returning `n-1` as the outcome bit otherwise. If the probabilities of a 1 or 0 bit are p and q respectively, this yields uniformly distributed bits because the joint probabilities are equal: pq==qp. However, it’s expensive.

Comment: @MarkRansom and Stef It's really interesting (to me) that you can take 10 bits of entropy (when you need only and irrational 9 point something bits), but if the 10 bits are more than 999 you get ~4.5 bits back for your next try.  At first glance this looks like free entropy generation (9.9+4.5 > 10) though it's probably not because of the the condition.

Comment: @fadedbee But the probability to get these 4.5 bits is extremely low (only 24/1024). In most cases you get 0 bits (with probability 1000/1024)

Comment: @fadedbee Clearly 9.97 + 4.5 > 10; the relation that links these numbers is 2^9.97 + 2^4.5 ≈ 2^10

Comment: @Stef I think that I've developed a more entropy-efficient algorithm: https://www.fadedbee.com/2024/02/13/random-numbers-under-a-maximum/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77966454/generating-random-number-in-a-non-power-of-2-range-from-random-bits/77991071#77991071

Comment: @MarkRansom Yours creates bias. [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLLTsMwEJQ45sA3jMQlLqnalAtChAu_wA2hym03raXYjpyN6n4Ll17go_ga7CRNgbI378zseB_vn_WBd9Ycjx8tl9P7r6vrDZXYklk6aTZWpyvFDTuSOoMRDwlCeBSYAzfoKTCtXpGLInKSaYPGopSu4-rAzSPXQzWQ1V4eGrRGldZpKBNLbAmv8wx6mr91kv1OVYQX11Jvd7L0mGCBWxjyfP6WGDkakwKL8anKkHkqYM5VhrTH499sDEfcOgP_C6CqoUuqx7SAns0WF0jstwOS0oXRKCbH1lYNlK6t42BSk-QeHMY3IFvimIiN9fDaVhWtWVkzqp9ta0LFJBnbj3ayTn-Is8EjzYVIktopw-mgS__f651AWAeW4z7SfN6FEKI_i-E6TlfyDQ) with n=3.

Comment: @Stef Small suggestions: `for bit in bitstream: x = x * 2 + bit` and `bitstream = map(getrandbits, repeat(1))`.

Comment: @KellyBundy What if my religion forbids me from shortcutting a `for`-loop with a `return`?

Comment: @Stef Then I guess you're a [sinner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75103547/12671057).

Comment: @KellyBundy yes I know about the bias, although I didn't at the time I left the comments.  See my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The technique you describe is called *Rejection Sampling*.  It's the only way I know to change the range of a random number without introducing a bias, i.e. making some numbers more common than others.

There's no way to know how many bits the technique will require, but unless you're using [Dilbert's random number generator](https://web.archive.org/web/20150123013256/http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) it will succeed eventually.

There's an idea that I had and expressed in comments.  When you know your random bits don't fit your criteria, there's no need to throw them all away - just throw out one bit and replace it with a new one.  After all, those bits were all random.  At first I suggested throwing out the top bit and putting the new one at the bottom, but that introduced a horrible bias - numbers 978 and over were twice as likely to be selected!  Because only large numbers are rejected, the upper bits are guaranteed to be 1 and those bits aren't random enough anymore.  I thought the solution would be to put the new bit at the top instead but that just moves the bias - now it's in the range 500-511, and the bias is worse at over 6x.

It took a bit of thought to figure out why there was a bias.  Those 9 bits, while they started out perfectly random, are no longer random once they've gone through the selection criteria.  You know for example that the top 4 or 5 bits are all one!  In fact there's no way to save an integral number of bits, because there's exactly 23 numbers that fail the criteria, and 23 is not a power of 2.  Even just taking a single bit will introduce a bias, for example the lowest order bit will be one 52% of the time and zero 48% of the time.

Here's a Python implementation of the idea.  **DO NOT USE THIS**, it's flawed.

```
def random_number(highest):
    max_bits = highest.bit_length()
    n = random.getrandbits(max_bits)
    while n > highest:
        new_bit = random.getrandbits(1)
        n = (n >> 1) | (new_bit << (max_bits - 1))
    return n
```

In contrast, here's your original idea which works perfectly.

```
def random_number(highest):
    max_bits = highest.bit_length()
    n = random.getrandbits(max_bits)
    while n > highest:
        n = random.getrandbits(max_bits)
    return n
```

I did some testing to see how many random bits were required to generate a million (1000000) numbers with each technique.

1. OP's algorithm as implemented above:  10229960
2. [Stef's
   algorithm:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77969606/5987)  10154569
3. My
   fatally flawed algorithm:  10045036

You can see why I was pursuing this approach.  It's a shame it didn't work.

Comment: I think you have to throw out all the bits and start anew; _cf_ Monty Hall problem.

Comment: @pjs I had this idea that I went on and on about in comments.  It wasn't until I actually coded it up that I discovered it was biased.  I'm still analyzing the reasons and I'll edit that in soon.

Comment: Aren't there 24 numbers that fail the criteria, not 23? (Not sure whether you're talking about the question's approach or your own with 9 bits somehow.)

Comment: In a sense, the OP's takes far fewer random bits than Stef's, since `getrandbits(1)` computes 32 bits and [throws 31 of them away](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/298bcdc185d1a9709271e61a4cc529d33483add4/Modules/_randommodule.c#L516). So Stef usually gets 320 underlying bits computed while the OP only gets 32 computed.

Comment: @KellyBundy it's 23, the numbers 1001 through 1023 (1000 is valid).  And I was sure my Dilbert link was to the Internet Archive version of the page, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: How is 1000 valid? The question says *"between 0 and 999 (inclusive)"* and *"if their value is less than 1,000, use that"*.

Comment: @KellyBundy I've looked at that question 20 times, how did I miss that?  As for highest=1 that's definitely a bug, but I'm not going to bother fixing it.

Comment: @KellyBundy that's a good suggestion.  I keep forgetting about `bit_length` because for a long time I was stuck on a version of Python that was too old to have it.  Plus I keep getting it confused with `bit_count`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method used now by GCC and Clang

https://lemire.me/blog/2019/06/06/nearly-divisionless-random-integer-generation-on-various-systems/

Comment: I had thought about posting this reference as well, but am not sure it answers the question. This algorithm has a noticeable impact on the speed by avoiding costly operations, but it's not clear whether it improves the number of bits required.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more [entropy-efficient algorithm](https://www.fadedbee.com/2024/02/13/random-numbers-under-a-maximum/).

The algorithm below is an entropy efficient way of generating unbiased random numbers, less than a maximum value "max", from a stream of random bits.

It is more entropy-efficient than sample-and-reject **if and only if "max" has a factor which is a positive power of two**.

It makes use of the fact that if the maximum has a factor which is a positive power of two, then we can decide whether a number will be too big by taking a number of random bits which are fewer than the length of the maximum (in binary).  The difference in the numbers of bits is the exponent in the maximum's power-of-two factor.

### Example:

If max is 1000, it has a factor of two-to-the-power-of-three (8).  1000 is a ten bit number.  But we only need to take seven bits to decide if a number 0..1023 is less than 1000.

```
        two_power == 3    log2(8)
             bits == 10   log2(1024)
 significant_bits == 7    10 - 3
```

We first generate 7 bits and shift them left three places, to give us:

```
                r == ..._000000??_?????000
```

We compare this with 1000:

```
              max == ..._00000011_11101000
```

So long as r >= max, we have to try again with another 7 bits.

Once r < max, we fill in the final three bits of precision:

```
                r == ..._000000??_????????
```

### Entropy Efficient Algorithm for Generating Random Numbers under a Maximum

```rust
const BITS_IN_U64: u32 = 64;

fn random_under_max(max: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    // How many bits do we need?
    let two_power = max.trailing_zeros();
    let bits = BITS_IN_U64 - max.leading_zeros();
    let significant_bits = bits - two_power;

    let mut r = u64::MAX;

    while r >= max {    
        // First collect the minimal amount of random bits which
        // will let us decide whether the random number is going to be less
        // than max.
        r = 0;
        for _ in 0..significant_bits {
            // Generate one random bit
            let b: bool = rng.gen();

            // and shift it into our imprecise random number.
            r = r << 1 | b as u64;
        }

        // Shift the inexact random number into the correct position.
        r = r << two_power;
    }

    // Now fill-in the precise value of this random number.
    r = r >> two_power; // Scrub out the insignificant zeros.
    for _ in 0..two_power {
        // Generate one random bit
        let b: bool = rng.gen();

        // and shift it into our random number.
        r = r << 1 | b as u64;
    }

    // Return the generated number.
    r
}
```